# Getting Error : Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below is my SQL Query

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @PRE_CD INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PRE_CD), 0) FROM  TBL_MAIN)

INSERT INTO TBL_MAIN
            (PRE_CD,
             PRE_DESC,
             PRE_REF_CD)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRESENTATION) + @PRE_CD,
       PRESENTATION,
       3
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT PRESENTATION
        FROM   Temp_Data
        WHERE  PRESENTATION NOT IN (SELECT PRE_DESC
                                    FROM   TBL_MAIN)) T

COMMIT;
```

on executing this query i'm getting error

`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: just make sure (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PRE_CD),0) FROM TBL_MAIN) does  not return more than one row

Comment: it returns only 1 row

Comment: because the above error simply means that you are trying to assign multiple values to some query or variable that only accepts one row (value)

Comment: @DharaShah - It can't return more than one row. An aggregate without a `GROUP BY` always returns a single row result.

Comment: Any reason why `PRE_CD` isn't an `IDENTITY` column anyway?

Comment: @MartinSmith i wasnt aware abt that, i was assuming a situation where if there are more than one values that are maximum and same :) that's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that code can cause it directly.

Probably you have a buggy `INSERT` trigger on the table that assumes that `INSERTED` will only contain a single row and fails for multi row inserts.